# angular 2 to avoid pyramid of doom http calls

Tags: angular, typescript

in angular 1 I could nest some http-calls and react on their result like this:

```js
this.$qSessionPromise
.then(() => {
    return this.Init();
})
.then(() => {
    return this.Services.GetData1("id1");
})
.then((data: model.DataType1) => {
    this.data = data;
 })
.then(() => {
    this.SetIsInitialized(true);
    this.handler = new MyHandler(this.data);
    this.RegisterEvents();
});
```

but in angular 2 I couldn't find a way to do something similar...

when I use the subscribe-method there is no way to ad another subscribe-method...

```js
    this.service.GetData1()
    .subscribe(data:model.DataType1 => {
       this.data = data;
   return this.Services.GetData2("id2");
    })
.subscribe(data:model.DataType2 => {
       this.data = data;
    })
```

is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.mergeMap()` instead of `.subscribe()` (except on the last one because without `.subscribe()` no HTTP call will be made

```
   this.service.GetData1()
   .mergeMap(data:model.DataType1 => {
       this.data = data;
       return this.Services.GetData2("id2");
   })
   .subscribe(data:model.DataType2 => {
       this.data = data;
   })
```

Comment: `.flatMap()` (for back-to-back rest calls) and `.forkJoin()` (`Promise.all`) operators come in handy too. Just wanted to mention :)

Comment: `.flatMap()` is only an alias to `mergeMap()` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md